# fetch() api does not send headers and body in "no-cors" mode?

Tags: javascript

I am sending POST request like this from browser and it is a cross platform request:

```
var reg_data = {"name": "John"};
                                    
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'token': 'value'
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(reg_data)
})
```

By the time the request reaches my back-end it does not contain token nor body.

Following is  my backend ruby code -

```
before_action :cors_preflight_check

   def cors_preflight_check
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Accept, Content-Type, token'
    end
```

I checked some articles it says it happens as the mode is set to "no-cors" the headers and body is restricted. It works fine with postman, but fails with browser. How do I solve this issue as I want to serve a cross platform request and also access the request headers and body?

Comment: `token` is indeed not part of this list: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#no-cors-safelisted-request-header-name The body however should be sent I think... But can't you simply set the domain you wish to allow in that preflight check and send a cors request?

Comment: @Kaiido can you please explain in more detail